# Regular expression to find code PHP

Tags: php, arrays, regex, algorithm, preg-match

I need help creating the regular expression which will pull out the information which i like, preferable place it into a array. for example

```
array[0] = FRQRTJQ;
array[1] = UAMN27I;
array[2] = RSP5RF2;

("Family Pack 2015,""Family Pack 2015"",10,365,FRQRTJQ"),  
(" Family Pack 2015,""Family Pack 2015"",10,365,**UAMN27I**"),   
("Family Pack 2015,""Bitdefender Family Pack 2015"",10,365,**RSP5RF2**"),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use `preg_match_all()`

```
<?php
$string = '("Family Pack 2015,""Family Pack 2015"",10,365,FRQRTJQ"),(" Family Pack 2015,""Family Pack 2015"",10,365,**UAMN27I**"), ("Family Pack 2015,""Bitdefender Family Pack 2015"",10,365,**RSP5RF2**"),';
$pattern = "/[A-Z0-9]{7}/";

preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Returns:

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(7) "FRQRTJQ" [1]=> string(7) "UAMN27I" [2]=> string(7) "RSP5RF2" } }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that was really helpful.

Comment: @Noob if it was helpful to you then accept the answer please